# Retry Not Working in Control Flow

Tags: ruby

I am trying to execute the below code:

```
animals = %w(dog cat horse goat snake frog)
count = 0

for animal in animals
    puts "The current animal is #{animal}"
    break if count == 10
    count += 1
    retry if animal == 'horse'
end
```

When I try to execute the file on IRB, I get the following output:

```
2.0.0-p247 :001 > load 'loopexit.rb'
SyntaxError: loopexit.rb:19: Invalid retry
    from loopexit.rb
2.0.0-p247 :002 >
```

Can anyone please advise what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Inside a `rescue` clause, [`retry`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/) causes Ruby to return to the top of the enclosing code (the `begin` keyword, or top of method or block) and try executing the code again.

But you need to use [`next`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/). It bumps an *iterator*, or a `while` or `until` block,to the *next* iteration, unconditionally and without executing whatever may remain of the block.

`retry` is not to use inside the *loops*.

You can write the code as below :

```
for animal in animals
    next if animal == 'horse'
    puts "The current animal is #{animal}"
    break if count == 10
    count += 1
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Ruby 1.9 `retry` cannot be used in loops anymore.

It used to jump to the begin of the first iteration. Sometimes you may still find books and tutorials that refer to Ruby 1.8, but that is not supported anymore.

Valid keywords in a loop are

- `next` which jumps to the begin of the next iteration
- `redo` which jumps to the begin of the current iteration
- `break` which ends the loop

Answer (score 0):

Use `next` instead of `retry`, as you want to skip the current iteration. `retry` is for exceptions, not loops.

However you also have an error in your logic: You want to skip the iteration *as soon* as you know that the animal is `horse`, so you should move the `next` statement at the top of the loop:

```
for animal in animals
    next if animal == 'horse'
    puts "The current animal is #{animal}"
    break if count == 10
    count += 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't guaranteed to do exactly what you want, but it's written in a more Ruby-like (and, to me, more sensible) way:

```
animals = %w(dog cat horse goat snake frog)

animals.each_with_index do |animal, i|
  next if animal == 'horse'
  puts "The current animal is #{ animal }"
  break if i == 10
end
```

We generally don't use `for` loops. Doing so exposes the intermediate variable, `animal` in this case, which contaminates the variable space needlessly. Instead, using `each`, the variable `animal` is limited to the `do` block, so variable space isn't wasted unnecessarily.

[`each_with_index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) passes a counter into the block as a parameter, making it easy to know how many have been seen, or what index value is current.

Of course, `break if i == 10` will never execute unless `animals` has more than 10 elements.

Comment: You could also use `(animals[0..10] - ['horse']).each do |animal| ... end`, depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: *which contaminates the variable space needlessly* - Can you explain, what do you mean by this?

Comment: @ArupRakshit In the OP's example, `animal` would still be defined outside the for loop.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I think what he's saying is that exposing `animal` outside the for loop is like "polluting the global namespace", except only within the current method/block scope. `animal` probably doesn't need to be available outside of the loop.

IMO that's not a big deal, and it's certainly not the main reason why I'd discourage using for loops, but it is a difference worth noting.